# Android - How would you do a sync between clients?

Tags: java, android, database

I am currently programming an app that need to keep track of datas accross multiples devices that are not under the same google account.

(Like me and my wife device).

I have been looking around and was thinking about mySQL but at that point I'm not sure.

What the app need to do :

When clicking on a button, connect to remote database, download one value, do some math then send back the result to save it in a database.

What type of database could I use to achieve that?

Comment: Use `Firebase` cloud NoSql database, it's perfect for your task.

Comment: Omg that souns perfect! thanks a lot!